# Is uint strictly positive

Tags: c

I want to assert that an unsigned int is strictly positive. I was debating between the following two options:

```
unsigned int i = 1;
assert(i > 0); /*option 1*/
assert(i != 0); /*option 2*/
```

I found myself stuck in a [Buridan's ass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass) dilemma. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: `unsigned int` can be `0`.

Comment: I know. That is why I need to assert.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question.

Comment: here's another one (just for the sake of messing with your dilemma): `assert(is_strictly_positive(x));`

Comment: @Olaf I think you are confusing `>` with `>=`

Comment: @BenjyKessler: Sorry; I removed the comment already

Comment: The declaration of `i` may be far away, and the reader of the code might have forgot the type. Then seeing `i != 0` could then mean that the reader thinks that it just can't be zero, which means it could just as well be a negative number. Using `i > 0` really means that `i` must be positive, which is the meaning of the test.

Comment: Note: On some architectures (mostly small MCUs) `>` might require more code. A dumb compiler (still used for such architectures) might not optimize that.

Comment: Also, be careful when using the [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) macro for runtime-checking. First of all it's only enabled as long as `NDEBUG`  is not defined, and many environments define `NDEBUG` for release-builds. Second of all, it will forcibly abort the program if the assertion fails, which might not always be a good solution for error handling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`assert(i > 0);` is more readable to other programmers that `i` is checked for positive integers and including the case for `i = 0`.

---

**Note:** As [Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) pointed in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272895/is-uint-strictly-positive/34272957#comment56287914_34272895) that keep in mind that *if the macro `NDEBUG` was defined at the moment `<assert.h>` was last included, the macro [`assert()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html) generates no code, and hence does nothing at all.*

Answer (score 3):

I prefer

```
assert(i > 0); /*option 1*/
```

For 2 reasons.

Firstly it's one less character, and characters cost money.

Secondly if your intent is to show the number is strictly positive this makes it clear even without the knowledge that i is an unsigned int.

Comment: Well, you would need to know it is unsigned, so you know you wouldn't have to test for negative values.

Comment: My point was if I want the number to be strictly positive, it's strictly positive with option 1 whether the number is unsigned or not.  With option 2, it's also strictly positive but I need an additional piece of information to confirm that when looking at the code.

Answer (score 2):

Both certainly generate the same code so **whatever conveys the overall function's goal** is the better selection:

```
unsigned int i = ...;
assert(i > 0); /*option 1*/
assert(i != 0); /*option 2*/
```

Option 1 works better in most cases as it is a positive assertion: what should the value be vs. what it should not be.  Usually this is easier to understand.  Also when the arithmetic nature of `i` is being tested, this is the way to go.

Option 2 works better in limited cases when `i` is solely used for its zero, or non-zero-ness - especially if it is a collection of logical bits whose arithmetic value is irrelevant.